# How to get data from a .docx file and store it into the clipboard?

Tags: c++, clipboard, docx, rtf

I don't know how to read (RTF)data from a .docx file and store the data into the clipboard, so I can copy it in a other .docx file via CTRL+V. I can't find any samples of how to do this.

My latest code question was 4,5 year ago, since I always figure it out on my own, but with this one I need some help

Okay, I managed to copy the data from a .docx to another .docx by using std::ios::binary.

```
/// Copy file contents
std::ifstream inputFile("test.docx", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int length = inputFile.tellg();
inputFile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
std::string fileContents;
fileContents.resize(length);
inputFile.read(&fileContents[0], length);
inputFile.close();

/// Paste file contents
std::ofstream outputFile("new.docx", std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);
outputFile.write(&fileContents[0], length);
outputFile.close();
```

I even managed to store some text(data) from a .txt file to the clipboard in format CF_TEXT. It works as I expected the text in .txt file is stored in the clipboard, and I can use CTRL+V.

```
int main () {
    std::vector<char> bytes = ReadAllBytes("test.txt");
    std::string x(bytes.begin(), bytes.end());
    std::cout << bytes.size() << std::endl;
    SaveClipboard(x.c_str());
}

void SaveClipboard(const char* text) {
    HGLOBAL global = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strlen(text) + 1); 
    memcpy(global, text, strlen(text));  //text size + \0 character
    if(OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, global);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
}

std::vector<char> ReadAllBytes(char const* filename) {
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    std::ifstream::pos_type pos = ifs.tellg();

    std::vector<char> result(pos);

    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    ifs.read(&result[0], pos);

    return result;
}
```

Okay now, how do I get the data from a .docx file and store this data in the clipboard so I can use CTRL+V in open .docx window.

I tried to use:

```
std::vector<char> bytes = ReadAllBytes("test.docx");
DWORD CF_RTF = RegisterClipboardFormat("Rich Text Format");
SetClipboardData(CF_RTF, global);
```

But then I get the result "PK____" on the clipboard when I paste it in a open .docx file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `docx` is a zip file containing XML files, you would need to unzip the file and then parse the XML in order to get access to the text. You'd probably be better off writing either a macro in word or using COM to manipulate word from c++.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, I will look into the unzip idea first

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was able to get the content of a .docx file by unzipping and retrieving the data from the document.xml stored in the .docx file. The problem is it gives me a XML representation of the data if stored in the clipboard. Any suggestions how to store the XML data in a variable that reconstructs the XML data so the clipboard knows it is RTF?

Comment: to quote my earlier comment "You'd probably be better off writing either a macro in word or using COM to manipulate word from c++"

Comment: I finally found the solution, I open the related richtext file with `ShellExecute` in the background and use `WM_COPY` to store the content of the file in the clipboard.